# Integral on a triangle with a non-holomorphic point inside

Tags: complex-analysis

This exercise comes from Stein & Shakarchi, ch 2 # 6.

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$, and let $T \subset \Omega$ be a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$. Suppose that $f$ is a function holomorphic in $\Omega$ except possibly at a point $w$ inside $T$. Prove that if $f$ is bounded in an open neighborhood of $w$, then $$ \int_T f(z) dz = 0 $$

I wanted to make sure that my solution is correct, it goes as follows:

Draw the lines from the vertices of the triangle $T$ to $w$.  Denote one of these lines by $[v_1, w]$.  We can integrate along this line, since $$\int_{[v_1, w]} f(z) dz = \lim_{w' \to w} \int_{[v_1, w']} f(z) dz$$ which is defined.  Then let the three smaller triangles formed be $T_1, T_2, T_3$.  Then $$\int_T f(z) dz = \int_{T_1} f(z) dz + \int_{T_2} f(z) dz + \int_{T_3} f(z) dz$$ since the additional lines we are integrating on cancel out through opposing orientations.  By Goursat's theorem, each of the three integrals is 0, so we are done.

I am wondering if we can even apply Goursat's theorem when $f$ is not holomorphic at one of the vertices of each of the sub-triangles by just doing a limit of integrals, as described above.  Is this correct?

Comment: That remains to be proved. Reducing the problem to one where the exceptional point is a vertex is a good first step. To handle the vertex case, consider a parallel to the side opposite the vertex that is close to the vertex.

Comment: Does the fact that the integral from the vertex to the exceptional point can be defined as the limit of an integral resolve the issue of integrating over a triangle where the exceptional point is a vertex?

Comment: Not quite, you still need to show that the integral is $0$ under the given conditions.

Comment: So, by drawing a line that is parallel to the opposite side, we get a trapezoid shape (around whose integral is 0 by Cauchy's theorem), and a smaller triangle of the same form..... Then can we just take the limit as the line moves toward the point to obtain that it is 0 by continuity of the integral?

Comment: Yes, that's it. The function is bounded, the length of the contour tends to $0$, so the ML inequality says the integral tends to $0$. (Since it's independent of the distance of the help line to the vertex, it's always $0$, but we only _know_ that a posteriori.)

Comment: Oh and that is where we use the boundedness in an open neighborhood. Thank you very much!

Comment: If $f$ is assumed continuously complex differentiable then proving this form of the Cauchy/Goursat integral theorem is not so complicated.