# Proving a generalized Goursat's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Steins and Shakarchi's *Complex Analysis* and I'm current looking at Excercise 6 from Chapter 2. It says:

> Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and let $T \subset \Omega$ be a triangle whose interior is also contained in $\Omega$. Suppose $f$ is holomorphic in $\Omega$ except possibly at a point $w$ inside $T$. Prove that if $f$ is bounded near $w$, then $$\int_T f(z)\, dz = 0$$

I'm aware of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2380507/integral-on-a-triangle-with-a-non-holomorphic-point-inside) but I'm unable to parse the geometric construction the comments are talking about. I imagine that the first step is probably two subdivide $T$ into three new triangles $T_1,T_2,T_3$ by connecting each vertex of $T$ to $w$ and observing that $$\int_T f \, dz = \int_{T_1} f + \int_{T_2} f + \int_{T_3} f$$ since we should have some cancellation. This is where it gets a bit murky for me:

(1.) Is this cancellation even justifiable since we don't have any information about whats going on at $w$? How can we be sure the integral is well defined if we are integrating over a point that is potentially a singularity?

(2.) Assuming that is fine, how do we show that each of the three integrals are zero?

Keeping in mind this is an introductory text book so I would like to keep my solution reasonably low tech.

From the question I linked it seems the way forward is set up some type of auxiliary contour and investigate some type of limit but I'm unsure of the details.

Comment: The simple answer is to retract onto small loops around each singularity, note bounded singularities don't affect results (i.e. Riemann Singularity Theorem) and conclude.

Comment: The retraction can be made more elementary by, for example, partitioning the region into tiny triangles of radius $\epsilon$ ($w$ must be in the interior of one of them) and integrating around each. Note this also follows quickly from Cauchy's Integral Formula or the Residue Theorem, which give the answer $0$ since a removable singularity has zero Laurent coefficients

Comment: I think I see. Basically you just draw a circle with radius $\epsilon$ small enough to be contained in $T$, then observe the desired contour integral around $T$ is equal to the contour integral around the circle. Lastly, just estimate the circle integral using the ML estimate.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I intended with my hint in the comment above. Well done!